# Excel change text colour if a select option is selected

Tags: excel

On my worksheet I have text in cell D12, currently this text is bold and red.

I have a select drop-down in F12, if an option is selected in the drop-down I would like the text in D12 to be black and bold. If the option is set back to nothing or empty I would like the text to go back to being red and bold.

Can this be done ?
Thanks

Comment: This can probably de done with conditional formatting

Comment: Could you explain how ? Thanks